# 'Document' is not convertible to 'StitchTask<Document>'. This error pops up after following the instructions on mongo cloud atlas

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb

I've been following along with tutorials on how to connect an iOS application written in swift which walks thorough a way to connect mongo to the application. I've set up a cluster on mongoDB Atlas and have initialized a collection to store data. I've also installed cocoapods and updated my podfile.

[imports to mongo, stitch, and extended json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFSkU.png)

[database code starts at stichClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd9vh.png)

I am fairly new to xcode and mongo and I'm not sure what it means when "'Document' is not convertible to 'StitchTask'.

I've been following the instructions on https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/getting-started/todo-ios/
and have set Google Cloud Platform. I would at least like to add something into the database and I believe the second image contains code that is close to that. I don't understand how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS SDK was recently updated to use PromiseKit, but the example code and the documentation were not updated at the same time.

In addition to the SDK changes, the steps for setting up Google Auth to work with iOS also changed, so you hit a perfect storm.

Both the [sample code](https://github.com/mongodb/stitch-examples/tree/master/todo/ios) and [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/tutorials/todo-ios/) have been updated. Hopefully that'll get you up and running.